# Why does Firefox ignore the `304 Not Modified` status sent by the webserver?

Tags: firefox, cache, https, web-development, lighttpd

For my site, Firefox 32.0 seems not to cache a CSS file of my Nikola 7.1.0 installation and ignores the `304 Not Modified` response by the webserver. What also puzzles me, is that it sends the 2nd request with a different `Accept:` header.

Chrome 37.0 does not show this behaviour and only requests the file once.

The first HTTP request Firefox sends is:

```
GET /assets/css/all-nocdn.css HTTP/1.1
Accept:  text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:  en-GB,en;q=0.5
Authorization:  …
Cache-Control:  max-age=0
Connection:  keep-alive
Host:  …
If-Modified-Since:  Mon, 14 Jul 2014 09:12:55 GMT
If-None-Match:  "2838446235"
Referer:  …
User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0



HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/css
Date: Fri, 12 Sep 2014 07:18:02 GMT
ETag: "2838446235"
Last-Modified: Mon, 14 Jul 2014 09:12:55 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.35
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

And the next HTTP request is:

```
GET /assets/css/all-nocdn.css HTTP/1.1
Accept:  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:  en-GB,en;q=0.5
Authorization:  …
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Connection:  keep-alive
Host:  …
Pragma:  no-cache
User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 22700
Content-Type: text/css
Date: Fri, 12 Sep 2014 07:26:42 GMT
ETag: "2838446235"
Last-Modified: Mon, 14 Jul 2014 09:12:55 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.35
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Vary: Accept-Encoding


…
```

(I actually replayed this using [HTTPie](http://httpie.org/), because Firefox does not allow to copy the server response as a whole. Copying the request headers is possible by clicking "Edit and Resend".)

What could be reasons for that behaviour? Does Firefox offer a way to see the reason for a HTTP request? (What Chrome calls "initiator".)

Please have a look at my [Screenshot of the Network section of the Firefox Developer Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR9lj.png) to see an overview of all requests in the timeline:
[image: Screenshot of the Network section of the Firefox Developer Toolbar]

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with Ubuntu? Maybe this should be moved to superuser.com?

Comment: The only thing I found that I could do is flag your comment for moderator attention :) Urging them to move the question to e.g. superuser.com.